# R: install.package() is not calling compilers on CentOS 6.5

Tags: r, linux, centos

R version: 3.1.1

I want to install [this package](https://github.com/ha0ye/rEDM). I downloaded the source and put it under my home directory. After that I ran `install.packages("~/rEDM/",repos=NULL,type="source")` to install from source. The error message I got is:

```
Installing package into ‘/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘rEDM’ ...
** libs
I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include    -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/bin/sh: I/usr/include/R: No such file or directory
make: [RcppExports.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include    -c block_lnlp.cpp -o block_lnlp.o
/bin/sh: I/usr/include/R: No such file or directory
make: [block_lnlp.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include    -c forecast_machine.cpp -o forecast_machine.o
/bin/sh: I/usr/include/R: No such file or directory
make: [forecast_machine.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include    -c lnlp.cpp -o lnlp.o
/bin/sh: I/usr/include/R: No such file or directory
make: [lnlp.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include    -c xmap.cpp -o xmap.o
/bin/sh: I/usr/include/R: No such file or directory
make: [xmap.o] Error 127 (ignored)
-L/usr/local/lib64 -o rEDM.so RcppExports.o block_lnlp.o forecast_machine.o lnlp.o xmap.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/bin/sh: line 2: -L/usr/local/lib64: No such file or directory
make: *** [rEDM.so] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rEDM’
* removing ‘/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rEDM’
Warning message:
In install.packages("~/rEDM/", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘/ghome/dwuab/rEDM/’ had non-zero exit status
```

Something is very wrong here, as R did not call the compiler at all.
The author of the package said this is due to R and/or GCC being misconfigured.

**My question**: is there anyone who knows what the problem is? Or how to troubleshoot the problem?

**Edit 1**: installing the package through zip file using command `install.packages("./master.zip",repos=NULL,type="source")` led to the following error message:

```
Installing package into ‘/d1/dwuab/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\n\0\0\0\0\0\x83h,H\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\0\t\0rEDM-master/UT\005\0\001Fj\x95VPK\003\004\n\0\0\0\b\0\x83h,H\x8ewq\xa1\030\0\0\0\034\0\0\0\031\0\t\0rEDM-master/.Rbuild'
Warning message:
In install.packages("./master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘./master.zip’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Edit 2**: I have no root privilege on the machine.

Comment: Have you tried calling `install.packages` on a tarball?

Comment: How do you try to install `rEDM`? I successfully installed it with `devtools::install_github("ha0ye/rEDM")`.

Comment: @Pascal using `devtools::install_github("ha0ye/rEDM")` produces virtually the same error.

Comment: Did you declare in your `.bashrc` a `R_HOME` or a `R_INCLUDE_DIR` or something like that?

Comment: @Pascal, No, I didn't declare either `R_HOME` nor `R_INCLUDE_DIR` in `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, calling `install.packages` on the zip file produced another kind of error. Please see the edited post.

Comment: In R, what is the output of `Sys.getenv("R_INCLUDE_DIR")`?

Comment: @Pascal, `[1] "/usr/include/R"`

Comment: Really strange, as the compiler claims it doesn't exist. Do you see something in a terminal with `ls /usr/include/R`? You should see `R.h` among other files.

Comment: I meant the tarball (tar.gz), not windows binary (.zip).

Comment: @yes, I saw `Rconfig.h  Rdefines.h  Rembedded.h  R_ext  R.h  Rinterface.h  Rinternals.h  Rmath.h  Rversion.h  S.h`

Comment: @Pascal The strangest thing is, the compilation commands should start with "gcc" or "g++". Instead "I/usr/include/R" was treated as an executable.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I unzipped the official zip file, and compressed it to tarball. Got the same "no such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I used EasyBuild to compile and install R 3.2.1 with GCC 4.9.3. The whole compiling and installing process took me several days ... Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following link...
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-install-gcc-c-c-compiler/

Comment: How would your link help?